# Nuxt + IOT (aws-iot-device-sdk)

Tags: aws-iot, nuxt.js

I create a plugin like this:

```js
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk')
var device = awsIot.device({
  keyPath: 'xxxxxx,
  certPath: 'xxxxxx,
  caPath: 'xxxxxx',
  clientId: 'xxxxx', 
  region: 'xxxxxx',
  host: 'xxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com'
})
```

It works, but displays an error message:

> C:\Sistemas\AM\nodemodules\aws-iot-device-sdk\common\lib\tls-reader.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: filesys.existsSync is not a function at webpackJsonp../nodemodules/aws-iot-device-sdk/common/lib/tls-reader.js.module.exports

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons of this error, i.e.,

1. Angular version > 4 or not and
2. Indenting alignment problem in the JsonP

```js
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var device = awsIot.device({
    endpoint: 'https://******************.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
    keyPath: '../aws/************-private.pem.key',
    certPath: '../aws/***********-certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: '../aws/***********-public.pem.key',
    clientId: "******************",
    region: "******" 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
 
//
// Replace the values of '<YourUniqueClientIdentifier>' and '<YourCustomEndpoint>'
// with a unique client identifier and custom host endpoint provided in AWS IoT.
// NOTE: client identifiers must be unique within your AWS account; if a client attempts 
// to connect with a client identifier which is already in use, the existing 
// connection will be terminated.
//
var device = awsIot.device({
   keyPath: 'xxxxxxxxx-private.pem.key',
  certPath: 'xxxxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: 'rootCA.pem',
  clientId: 'MyConnect',
   host: 'xxxxxxx.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
});
 
//
// Device is an instance returned by mqtt.Client(), see mqtt.js for full
// documentation.
//
device
  .on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connect');
    //device.subscribe('topic_1');
    device.publish('MyConnectPolicy', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 'NodeJS server connected...'}));
  });
 
device`enter code here`
  .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
    console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
  });
```